# Averaging last N lines of column M of a file - Terminal

Tags: awk, terminal, tail

I wanted to compute an average of the last N lines of column M of a file. I found that the best solution is to use `tail` to get last N lines and pipe it to `awk`. For my case, `N=200` and `M=2`. The resulting command would be:

```
tail -n 200 -f filename.asc | awk '{ total += $2 } END { print total/NR }'
```

However, I am not getting any result. In fact, the terminal does not return. I tried `tail` separately and it outputs the last 200 rows fine, but does not work combined with `awk`.

I also tried using `unbuffer` (before the `tail`) as one of the solutions suggested [this](https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk), but still not solved yet. Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Remove `-f` from `tail`

Comment: Perfect! Can you explain in detail as answer?

Comment: @Thor Indeed without the `-f`, `tail` returns the terminal if used standalone. This was not the case earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running `tail` with `-f` (follow mode), it never terminates; and `awk` runs the `END` block at the end-of-input, thus it will never terminate. Remove the `-f` and it should work.

Comment: If this is related to another process, consider `tail -f --pid=PID` where `PID` is the process ID of the command generating the output.  When that command completes (meaning the PID is no longer active), `tail` will complete and `awk`'s `END` stanza will trigger.